# start date should not be greater than end date bootstrap date picker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I need to disable past dates and also should not allow to select end date less than start date and start date greater than end date.

```
*css included*
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css') }}">
```

*HTML Included*
It is my laravel project.

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-3">
    <div class='input-group date' data-provide="datepicker" id='fromdatepicker' >
        {!! Form::text('from_date', null,['id' => 'from_date', 'class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder'=> '-From Date-']) !!}
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="calendar-icon-bg"> </span>
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
        </span>
     </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-3">
    <div class='input-group date' data-provide="datepicker" id='todatepicker' >
        {!! Form::text('to_date', null,['id' => 'to_date', 'class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder'=> '-To Date-']) !!}
         <span class="input-group-addon">
             <span class="calendar-icon-bg"></span>
             <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
         </span>
     </div>
</div>
```

*js*

```
<script src="{{ asset('assets/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js') }}"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
    var nowDate = new Date();
    var today = new Date(nowDate.getFullYear(), nowDate.getMonth(), nowDate.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);
    $("#fromdatepicker").datepicker({
        startDate: today,
        autoclose: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        onSelected: function(selected) {
            $("#todatepicker").datepicker("option","minDate", selected)
        }
  });
  $("#todatepicker").datepicker({
      autoclose: true,
      numberOfMonths: 1,
      onSelected: function(selected) {
          $("#fromdatepicker").datepicker("option","maxDate", selected)
      }
  });  
});
</script>
```

Please help me.

Comment: Use minDate:'D' property past dates will be disabled.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple example based on your requirements. End date will never be same or before start date. And past dates are disabled.

```js
function populateEndDate() {
  var date2 = $('#dateStart').datepicker('getDate');
  date2.setDate(date2.getDate() + 1);
  $('#dateEnd').datepicker('setDate', date2);
  $("#dateEnd").datepicker("option", "minDate", date2);
}

$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#dateStart").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
    minDate: 'dateToday',
    onSelect: function(date) {
      populateEndDate();
    }
  }).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
  $('#dateEnd').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
    minDate: 1,
    onClose: function() {
      var dt1 = $('#dateStart').datepicker('getDate');
      var dt2 = $('#dateEnd').datepicker('getDate');
      if (dt2 <= dt1) {
        var minDate = $('#dateEnd').datepicker('option', 'minDate');
        $('#dateEnd').datepicker('setDate', minDate);
      }
    }
  }).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<label for="">start</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="dateStart" name="start">
<label for="">end</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="dateEnd" name="end">
```

Answer (score 1):

Suggested answer has the correct idea, but it's for `jQuery datepicker` instead of bootstrap datepicker. Here's how it works with `Bootstrap datepicker (1.9.0)`:

```
$("#dateStart").datepicker( {
    //settings
    startDate: new Date('2016-02-02'),
    endDate: new Date()
}).on('changeDate', function(ev) {
    //Get actual date objects from both
    var dt1 = $('#dateStart').data('datepicker').viewDate;
    var dt2 = $('#dateEnd').data('datepicker').viewDate;
    if (dt2 < dt1) {
        //If #dateEnd is before #dateStart, set #dateEnd to #dateStart
        $('#dateEnd').datepicker('update', $('#dateStart').val());
    }
    //Always limit #dateEnd's starting date to #dateStart's value
    $('#dateEnd').datepicker('setStartDate', $('#dateStart').val());
});

$("#endStart").datepicker( {
    //settings
    startDate: $('#dateStart').val(),
    endDate: new Date()
})
```